# EditContext.IsModified still false after unchecking checkbox

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have some checkboxes on an EditForm and I'm getting inconsistent behavior with EditContext.IsModified(). When you click **open** button, uncheck the first checkbox and click "OK", you see that IsModified() still returned false. Please refer below sample code.

```
<button @onclick="OnOpen">Open</button>


@if (_weatherForecast != null)
{
    @if (_wasModified.HasValue)
    {
        <p>EditContext.IsModified() = @_wasModified</p>
        <p>WillRain = @_weatherForecast.WillRain</p>
        <p>WillSnow = @_weatherForecast.WillSnow</p>
    }
    @if (_isVisible)
    { 
                <EditForm Model="@_weatherForecast" OnValidSubmit="OnValidSubmit">
                    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col">
                            <label>Will rain </label>
                            <input type="checkbox" @bind="@_weatherForecast.WillRain" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col">
                            <label>Will snow </label>
                            <input type="checkbox" @bind="@_weatherForecast.WillSnow" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="e-footer-content">
                        <button> Ok</button>
                    </div>
                </EditForm>
    }

}
@code {
    private bool _isVisible = false;
    private WeatherForecast _weatherForecast;
    private bool? _wasModified;

    private void OnValidSubmit(EditContext editContext)
    {
        _wasModified = editContext.IsModified();
        _isVisible = false;
    }

    private void OnOpen()
    {
        _weatherForecast = new WeatherForecast { WillRain = true, WillSnow = false };
        _wasModified = null;
        _isVisible = true;
    }

    public class WeatherForecast
    {
        public bool WillRain { get; set; }
        public bool WillSnow { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you want EditForm support you will have to use `<InputCheckbox />` instead of `<input type="checkbox" />`

In your case

```
<InputCheckbox @bind-Value="_weatherForecast.WillRain" />
```